# java - 400 when posting JSONObject to Restful Web Service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, http-status-code-400

I am trying to implement post functionality to my restful web service. However, whenever I try to post data using my post client, the server always returns a 400 Bad Request Exception.

Below is my post client:

```
public static HttpResponse post(String url, JSONObject data) throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringEntity json = new StringEntity(data.toString());
    json.setContentType("application/json");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.setEntity(json);
    return client.execute(post);
}
```

Below is the method header for my server side method:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/add")
public String addApp(@PathParam("device") String device, JSONObject json) {
```

Whenever I run the program, I get the following HttpResponse from my post method:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Server: nginx, Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 21:48:12 GMT, Content-Type: text/plain, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Connection: keep-alive, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6)]
```

What are some possible causes for this problem?

Comment: May be any special characters?

Comment: Special characters in the JSON string or in the URL?

Comment: You kinda have to give more information regarding what rest library are you using? Are you using other rest webservice calls which work fine? general setup etc etc etc

Comment: I am using jersey and the apache http library. I have a test post method that is working and 3 get methods that also work. It seems to be a problem only with one of my methods.

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing the JSONObject parameter server side with a Map<String, String>. Must be some kind of problem with serializing/deserializing of JSONObjects in jersey. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You specify a PathParam argument in your server signature but do not have a corresponding entry in the @Path annotation. I cannot tell from your client signature if you are already adding the device string to the URL but I believe you want something like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/add/{device}")
public String addApp(@PathParam("device") String device, JSONObject json) {
```

This is the key part:

```
@Path("/add/{device}")
```

With this Jersey will know where to look for the String that should be populated into device.

Comment: I specify the PathParam device in my class header. Thanks for the input though.